# Fixed div over absolute?

Tags: html, css

I want to create similiar page to [this.](http://makedirectory.co/) Especially I am interesed in that image with a flag. I tried to make something similiar to that and this is what I already managed to do: [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bufbond/uc2yZ/)

Html:

```
<div id="logo"> <a href="#"><img src="http://s20.postimg.org/9sr84gnw9/logo.png" alt="logo"></img></a> 
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="Marsrutai.html">Maršrutai</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Nuotraukos.html">Nuotraukos</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="Apie mane.html">Apie mane</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="Dviraciai.html">Dviračiai</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="Kontaktai.html">Kontaktai</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="header">
         <h1>MARŠRUTAI</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 8px 8px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 8px 9px;
    background-color: #282828;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}

#header {
    background-image:url(http://s20.postimg.org/gcpvgfth8/header.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    text-top:50%;
    color: white;
    top:70px;
    left:0;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:351px;
/*bacground gradients: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/# */
    background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 8px 8px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 8px 9px;
    background-color: #282828;
    background-size: 16px 16px;

    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}

#logo {
    position:fixed;
}

ul {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px #444;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 32%;
    right: 25%;
    top:15px;
}


 ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
}


 ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 5px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


 ul li a:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #CACACA;
```

As you can see, when you scrool down, content div with pisition:absolute, covers all other divs with position:fixed. But I want that when you scrool down, content div would cover just header div and logo and ul would stay on top of everything. Just like in [this page.](http://makedirectory.co/)

I'm not sure that I'm doing it right because I'm newbie at creating html. Is there any other way to make something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an higher z-index on your logo and nav and it will work as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, and make sure you're applying the z-index to the outermost div, since child divs are restricted by their parent z-indexes-